# Comprehensive guide to Operator Overloading in Python

Tags: python

Is there a comprehensive guide to operator overloading anywhere? Preferably online, but a book would be fine too. The description of the [operator module](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/operator.html) leaves a lot out, such as including operators that can't be overloaded and missing the r operators or providing sensible defaults. (Writing these operators is good practice, but still belongs in a good reference)

Comment: The document you are looking for is [here in Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames)

Answer (score 53):

Python's operator overloading is done by redefining certain special methods in any class.
This is [explained](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) in the Python language reference.

For example, to overload the addition operator:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __add__(self, x):
...         return '%s plus %s' % (self, x)
... 
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj + 1
'<__main__.MyClass object at 0xb77eff2c> plus 1'
```

Comment: What if I want to create operators like ∪ to create a set theory class where I could do operations like A ∪ B? Would it not be possible, because pyhton does not have a method for ∪?

Comment: Any benefit/drawback of this method?

Comment: @Divan you can override `__and__` (`&`) to represent an union (e.g. `A & B`), in fact, Python already has [a set theory implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) that does exactly that :)