# Asterisk for multiplication and duplication

Tags: python

I am confused with the use of `*` in python, sometimes it duplicates and sometimes it multiply. Is there a rule of thumb to follow here?

Comment: It entirely depends on the class that implements the `__mul__` method. For e.g. `str * n` will `return` `str` concatinated `n` times, while `int*n` will `return` the arithmetic evaluated value

Comment: It can even do something completely different. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400635/comprehensive-guide-to-operator-overloading-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both operands for * are numbers then the result is another number. If one operand is a string and the other is a number then it is the string repeated the given number of times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using * with a string object then it will return you concated string with n times.
However, if you use it with numbers then it will work as mathematical multiplication operator.

```
3 *2 =6

str*3
-> strstrstr
```

Comment: Thank you! Your illustration makes it easy to understand!